# is iteration a recursion?

Tags: recursion, iteration

i am confused. 
**is iteration a recursion too?**

In recursion, everything is processed in stack, does iteration(loops) are also processed in stack?

if we go deep into their processing, recursion's time and space complexity increases according to the condition, whereas iteration time complexity increases by space complexity remains constant.

can anyone clarify me more deeply on this topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they're different concepts.

- When iterating over a problem, you're solving it step by step (iterative) and in one layer.
- When using recursion, you're solving a problem layer by layer by recursive calls ("code calling itself again").

It's possible (and very likely) to combine both concepts in real code.

For example, to walk through some tree structure (JSON or XML), you'd typically end up with some function like this (pseudo code):

```
function parseNode(node) {
    // process this node
    switch (node.type) {
        // ...
    }

    foreach (child in node.children) // iterate over all child nodes
        parseNode(child) // this is the recursive call
}
```

Let's assume you've got the following tree with nodes:

```
  A
  |
B-+-C
|   |
E F-+-G
```

To start parsing the tree, you'd call `parseNode(A)`.

This would trigger the processing in the following order: A, B, E, C, F, G

As you can see, this will walk the tree branch by branch. When going down by one step/depth, you've got a recursive call. Whenever you switch to the next sibling, you're iterating.

Comment: okay i am clear. recursion is processed on stack over stack over stack etc...
and iteration processed in the same stack (or we could also make recursive call inside a iterator)

Comment: i got confused by seeing a code of LISP.
LISP does not have iteration/loops, but we can make our own iteration in that, this is the code by seeing i got very confused:

(DEFINE (+ X Y)
(IF (= X 0) 
Y
(+ (-1 + X) (1 + Y))))

okay, what i am clear is, this code behaves like iterator.

Answer (score 3):

Iteration is not recursion.  However,  there is a special case of recursion called tail recursion which could be optimized to the iteration.  Tail recursion happens when the last operation of your function is calling the function again.  In this case there is no need to save anything on the stack and compiler simply inserts a jump back to the start of the function.

Here is more details [What is tail recursion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33923/what-is-tail-recursion)

Also if you want to gain deep understanding of the subject.  Read this excellent book. http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book.html

Answer (score 1):

Major difference in time/space complexity between code running `recursion` vs `iteration` is caused by this :

as `recursion` runs it will create new [stack frame](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack#The_stack_and_frame_pointers) for each recursive invocation. Each of such frames consumes extra memory, due to local variables, address of the caller, etc.
When recursion reaches its end all those frames will start unwinding.

Therefore recursion tends to consume much more stack memory and is dangerous when its runtime depth is unknown and it could consume *all stack memory* allocated for current thread, in which case you will have [Stack Overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow) : )

Iteration does not have this problem, they consume constant amount of stack memory, as you stated in the question yourself.

It is possible to replace implementation of recursion with iteration using [stack (data structure)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28abstract_data_type%29), and this is sometimes done for the reasons stated above.

And iteration could also be converted into recursive implementation with tail recursion.

Please read more at [Recursion vs Iteration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29#Recursion_versus_iteration)

Answer (score 1):

Most of the existing answers argument by referring to the way recursion is implemented in procedural languages like C, C++, Pascal, Java, etc.
There recursion is solved by a new stack frame and iteration are solved within the same stack frame.

I would like to add that **beside the technical implementation differences they are also different in a conceptual way**.

**So if I rephrase your question to: Are recursion and iteration the same beside the technical compiler specific solution?**

**The answer is also: NO!**
Try to solve the famous [Fibonacci](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) example recursive and iterative.

```
Fib(n) = Fib(n-1) + Fib(n-2)
Fib(1) = 1
Fib(0) = 0
```

Recursive way:

```
Fib(5) = Fib(4) + Fib(3)
Fib(5) = Fib(3) + Fib(2) + Fib(2) + Fib(1)
Fib(5) = Fib(2) + Fib(1) + Fib(1) + Fib(0) + Fib(1) + Fib(0) + Fib(1)
Fib(5) = Fib(1) + Fib(0) + Fib(1) + Fib(1) + Fib(0) + Fib(1) + Fib(0) + Fib(1) 
Fib(5) = 1 + 0 + 1 + 1 + 0 + 1 + 0 + 1
Fib(5) = 5
```

**Observe how more and more space is needed in each line!**

Plus operations: 7
The runtime from the recursive approach is O(n!), which is horrible.

Iterative way:

```
Fib(0) = 0
Fib(1) = 1
Fib(2) = 0 + 1 = 1
Fib(3) = Fib(2) + Fib(1) = 2
Fib(4) = Fib(3) + Fib(2) = 3
Fib(5) = Fib(4) + Fib(3) = 5
```

**Observe how each line has the same length!**

Plus operations: 4
Runtime is O(n)

So: Always prefer an iterative solution over an recursive one if possible!

Answer (score 0):

Recursion involves a function/method calling itself. Iteration will be part of the body of a single function usually, so it's not calling itself.